# Sort Table Columns in certain order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say if I have the following records:

```
    ID  Type

    1   AUY
    2   NGD
    3   AUY
    4   NGD
    5   BUL
```

I like to sort it by Type so that "AUY" and "NGD" are sorted alphabetically but "BUL" is always at the end.

So it would look like this:

```
    AUY
    AUY
    NGD
    NGD
    BUL
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table is called table_1, you can do this with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [table_1]
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [Type] = 'BUL' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END),
    [Type]
```

Alternatively, you could add a new column for order priority and use that if you want something more scalable.

Comment: I upvoted, but you should fix the single quotes in the answer.  The `case` return values don't need quotes, and the quotes are wrong around "BUL".

Comment: While the case return quotes aren’t necessary, they still work. I can remove them though. Not sure what you mean about the quotes around ‘BUL’. Those are correct.

Comment: What was wrong with them? I see no difference. Maybe different formatting because I’m using mobile?

Comment: @reynoldsbj . . . That is interesting.  They were curly single quotes.  The quotes in the `case` are fine, but superfluous (why type them if you don't need them).  And it stops working if you have more than 9 or 10 conditions.

Comment: Weird, I typed the same single quote on both parts... I blame autocorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
...
ORDER BY CASE [Type] WHEN 'AUY' THEN 1
                     WHEN 'NGD' THEN 2
                     WHEN 'BUL' THEN 3
                     ELSE 4
         END;
```

Comment: ... Or better: `ORDER BY IIF([Type] = 'BUL', 1, 0), [Type]` - assuming more than 3 distinct types...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks. How would you do it if there are more than 3 distinct types and you want 'BUL' always at the end.

Comment: @NatePet exactly as I wrote in the comment... The point is to first order by the result of type = `bul`, and then by type.